# How to verify user ios sing in with google plus account ? server side

Tags: ios, authentication, google-plus, google-signin

I build a login  button in my ios app . i have followed this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in).

the login at my ios app work very fine. and i succeed to receive the auth object :

```
{accessToken="***********", refreshToken="*****", code="*******", expirationDate="2015-07-27 11:00:07 +0000"}
```

also i succeed to get the one time auth Code

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode;
```

now what should i do. according to the document, i should send the `homeServerAuthorizationCode` to my server. then exchange it with access token. but it doesn't mention how i could do that.

I found this article https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow but it just describe How to get access token . it doesn't show How to do that !

Also after i succeed to retrieve the token. How to call the google plus api. to retrieve user profile for example ?

Comment: Depending on your needs you can just send the `accessToken` to the server (over HTTPS) and use that to verify their profile.

Comment: @abraham thank you for your response. could you please provide a documentation that describe How tor retrieve user profile by the token ? thanks

Comment: [People.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get)

Comment: Never send `accessToken` off device.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to install the Google client package in your project

```
"google/apiclient": "^2.0.0@RC"
```

Then from your IOS authorized array, you can find a "server_code":"**********" . From this server code you can get new authenticate result (acees_token,refresh_token,expire etc) from server side.Please go through the below code

```
 $redirect_uri = 'http://******/gplusresponse';
  $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setClientId('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
 $client->setClientSecret('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');
 $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
 $client->setAccessType("offline");
 $client->setScopes(array(
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write'    
 ));

 $token=$client->authenticate(YOUR_SERVER_CODE);
print_r($token);
```

It will display a new token result array

```
{ "access_token": "*******************", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 3600, "refresh_token": "***************", "id_token": "***************" }
```

Now you can verify the user by giving the access token in the url en point with method as GET

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/?access_token=YOUR_NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The result will displays the authorized user profile.